# List inside struct in c++

Tags: c++

I have a list inside a struct in c++; I just want to insert elements to this list, as normal.

My structs are:

```
// A structure to represent an adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    std::list<int> adjacents;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};

// A structure to represent an adjacency list
struct AdjList
{
    int pos;
    struct AdjListNode *head; // pointer to head node of list
};

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};

struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists. Size of array will be V
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));


    // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;
    }

    return graph;
}
```

When I try to aceess:

```
graph->array[position].head->adjacents->push_back(number);
```

It just prompts this to me:

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Sorry, I have no clue about this error.

Comment: Hint: post all your code; like the one that defines graph, and so on. You see, most likely, you made some mistake in initializing your data structure; and something in your chain of "references" is NULL. Without that code, we can't tell you whats causing your problem!

Comment: try `graph.array->head->adjacents.push_back(number);`

Comment: A debugger can point to the problem. Maybe `position` is negative or greater or equal than `V`.

Comment: I see no code where you (a) build your graph, and (b) execute the code you say causes seg-fault. A debugger on your side is the best tool for solving this problem, especially since you're the only one that can actually produce it.

Comment: Ok, I am adding the code.

Comment: Just for you to have an idea, when I change the list member of the structure by and integer, I can access that integer, but the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault comes from

```
graph->array[position].head->adjacents.push_back(number);
```

with

```
graph->array[position].head = NULL;
```

I suppose that you have implicit struct invariant in your code since you have two lists that are likely to be connected: the linked list starting at `AdjList::head` and iterating through `AdjNode::next` and the list `AdjNode::adjacent`.

To keep the connection you can add a (C style) function that adds an element in both lists.

```
void
addAdjacent(AdjList& list, int adjacent) {
    // struct AdjListNode* newNode = (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = new AdjListNode;
    newNode->next = list.head;
    list.head = newNode;
    newNode->dest = 0;
    newNode->weight = 0;
    newNode->adjacents = std::list<int>(); // undefined behavior with malloc
    newNode->adjacents.push_back(adjacent);
}
```

Note that it is a bad idea to mix C style (malloc/free) with C++ style (especially with the containers of the Standard Template Library). The commented part of my code creates a segmentation fault since a `std::list` has not its fields filled with 0.

At the end the following `main` function works even if it has many memory leaks (see the valgrind tool)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   struct Graph* graph = createGraph(2);
   addAdjacent(graph->array[0], 1);
   addAdjacent(graph->array[1], 2);
   free(graph);
   return 0;
}
```

A C++-98 solution (without any memory leaks) could be:

```
// A structure to represent an adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    std::list<int> adjacents;
    struct AdjListNode* next;

    AdjListNode() : dest(0), weight(0), next(NULL) {}
};

// A structure to represent an adjacency list
struct AdjList
{
    int pos;
    struct AdjListNode *head; // pointer to head node of list

    // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    AdjList() : pos(0), head(NULL) {}
    ~AdjList()
      { while (head) {
          struct AdjListNode* temp = head;
          head = head->next;
          delete temp;
        }
      }

    void addAdjacent(int adjacent)
      { struct AdjListNode* newNode = new AdjListNode;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        newNode->adjacents.push_back(adjacent);
      }
};

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists. Size of array will be V
    Graph(int v) : V(v), array(NULL)
      { if (v >= 0 && v <= 1000)
          array = new struct AdjList[v];
        else
          throw std::bad_alloc();
      }
    ~Graph()
      { delete [] array; }
};

int main() {
   struct Graph* graph = new Graph(2);
   graph->array[0].addAdjacent(1);
   graph->array[1].addAdjacent(1);
   delete graph;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm checking that solution now. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you! That  indeed solved my problem for now. I'm not a c++ specialist, as you see. xD

Comment: After adding a big number of vertices I  noticed that there was a problem. As the graph should be undirected, it is normal that a vertex 0 points to 1 and 1 points to 0. So, when you do like:
graph->array[0].addAdjacent(1);  
graph->array[1].addAdjacent(0);

graph->array[1].addAdjacent(2);
graph->array[2].addAdjacent(1);

The output would be: 
Vertex: 0 is adjacent to: 1
Vertex: 1 is adjacent to: 2
Vertex: 2 is adjacent to: 1
What is clearly not correct. Any ideas @Franck?

Comment: @wagnerdelima As currently designed, the list `AdjListNode::adjacents` should only have one element. The linked list formed with the chain composed with the `AdjListNode::next` provides the other elements of the list. Hence if you consider the class `AdjListNode` as an edge between two vertices, you can replace `adjacents` by an `int nextVertex` and an `int previousVertex`, and also add two fields `std::set<int> nextTransitiveClosure` and `std::set<int> previousTransitiveClosure`. And `AdjList` could contain an `nextHead` and a `previousHead` that are the forward and backward edges.