# List inside struct memory leak?

Tags: c++, graph

Some days ago I wrote this question: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439591/list-inside-struct-in-c)

Where I asked how to insert elements in a list inside a graph struct. 
I've been writing more code and reached a point I cannot move forward.

I am posting the code just to make you have an idea:

```
//data_structures.h

#include <list>

// A structure to represent an adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    std::list<int> adjacents;
    struct AdjListNode* next;

    AdjListNode() : dest(0), weight(0), next(NULL) {}
};

// A structure to represent an adjacency list
struct AdjList
{

    struct AdjListNode *head; // pointer to head node of list

    //Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    AdjList(): head(NULL) {}
    ~AdjList()
    {
        while (head) {
            struct AdjListNode* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    void addAdjacent(int adjacent) {
        struct  AdjListNode* newNode = new AdjListNode;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        newNode->adjacents.push_back(adjacent);
    }

};

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists. Size of array will be V
    Graph(int v) : V(v), array(NULL) {
        if(v >= 0) {
            array = new struct AdjList[v];
        }
        else {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
    }

    ~Graph() {delete [] array;}

};


//main.cpp

int main()
{
    // create the graph given in above figure
    struct Graph* graph = new Graph(2);

    graph->array[0].addAdjacent(1);
    graph->array[1].addAdjacent(0);


    for(int i = 0; i < graph->V; i++) {
        for (list<int>::iterator it = graph->array[i].head->adjacents.begin();
             it != graph->array[i].head->adjacents.end(); ++it) {

            cout << "Vertex: " << i << " is adjacent to: " << *it << endl;
            cout << "Amount: " << graph->array[i].head->adjacents.size() << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

As the graph is undirected, the output when zero is connected to 1 and vise-versa (graph->array[0].addAdjacent(1); array[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439591/list-inside-struct-in-c).addAdjacent(0);) is:

Vertex: 0 is adjacent to: 1
Vertex: 1 is adjacent to: 0

However, adding more vertices (let's say, just one more) connected to vertex 0, for instance:

change this:

```
graph->array[0].addAdjacent(1);
graph->array[1].addAdjacent(0);
```

by

```
graph->array[0].addAdjacent(1);
graph->array[1].addAdjacent(0);

graph->array[0].addAdjacent(2);
graph->array[2].addAdjacent(0);
```

would output this:

Vertex: 0 is adjacent to: 2

Vertex: 1 is adjacent to: 0

Vertex: 2 is adjacent to: 0

What is clearly not correct. It is like vertex 0 is being overwritten, somehow. Any help, please?

Comment: If your creation still say `Graph(2)` then there's definitely going to be problems because that would be undefined. (There's no need for dynamic allocation there, btw.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just didn't change the creation in the post, bu in my code it is 4, definitely..